# Mitigate autocorrelation in time series with AR(2) process

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, residuals, autoregressive

I have a dataframe with 4000 companies and I have calculated a liquidity measure of each of the company in the dataframe. Liquidity is highly persistent. And my analysis shows that in these indiviual companies in my dataframe depict strong  first order autocorrelation. So, as suggested by literature I should transform this liquidity measure of each indiviual company by AR(2). By following AR(2) process equation

[image]

Where, Ct i is a measure of liquidity for stock i at month t, x is the number of lags included in the autoregressive process, and ut i is the residuals in liquidity for stock i at month t. 
I am unable to understand how this transformation works, what will be the new values of the each company. What I have to do with the residuals because what I read it says to extract the residual of each and subtract from original series.If I subtract the original value from residual won't it result in predicted value. I would appreciate if you could help me understand this in simple manner.

Why I want to carry out this is because I'm applying a liquidity adjusted CAPM to my data.And I have to calculate betas for indiviual companies based on equations of the model as follows
[image] Where,β1 is similar to the market beta of the CAPM except for additional term that is realted to the trading cost in the denominator. The remaining systematic risk components are associated with liquidity. β2 represents liquidity commonality, that is, the co-movement between individual stock liquidity and market liquidity.β3
measures the co-movement between stock returns and market liquidity.β4
captures the co-movement between individual liquidity and market returns.

For this purpose I have to mitigate the autocorrelation in the time series.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Are you trying to forecast something, test a hypothesis, describe a process or what? The recommendation will depend on the goal.

Comment: @RichardHardy I have updated my post according to your question realtiong to it. I hope it helps to understand what I am trying to ask here. I would really appreciate your help here.

Comment: Now it is clearer, but still I would like to get a little more information. Could you briefly show how you would obtain $\beta^{1i}$ if there was no autocorrelation in the data? Do you have data on $r_t^i$, $r_t^M$, $c_t^i$, $c_t^M$? What model(s) do you use to obtain $\text{E}_{t-1}(r_t^M)$, $\text{E}_{t-1}(c_t^i)$ and $\text{E}_{t-1}(c_t^M)$?

Comment: When you are applying the liquidity-adjusted CAPM, what is the model equation and what will you be using the model for?

Comment: @RichardHardy actually I haven't estimated any beta yet because this AR(2) is to be performed before carrying out the estimation for beta. I have to form decile portfolios of the companies in my dataset. I will estimate these betas in the decile portfolios and then assign the resulting beta to each company in the portfolio. C i t is a Percent quoted spread.

Comment: I have to test hypothesis regarding the systematic comovements in the liquidity risk and stock return.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34209/discussion-between-richard-hardy-and-aquarius).

Comment: @RichardHardy you mentioned to me that arima in R would give you a residual series that is as long as the original series.So, shall I use all of the residuals or drop the first to residuals as I have 2 lag?. And how ARIMA estimates residual series as long as the original. I have the residuals series. I would really appreciate your advice here.

Comment: What will you use the residuals for?

Comment: Rank the stocks and form decile portfolios and then use them for the beta estimations as mentioned above.

Comment: I don't see why you would use less than the full sample that is available to you. If you need lagged residuals, you have to cut the newest observations (one for lag one, two for lag two, etc.).